# Ember: How to access another model data in a dynamic segment template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

In a dynamic segment template, how do you display data from a model using the route ?

so for example I have those three routes with `phone_id` as dynamic segment

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('phones');
  this.route('phone', {path: 'phones/:phone_id'});
  this.route('numbers');
});
```

in  `phones/:phone_id` template, I am trying to show all the numbers model. so in `phone.js` route, I tried to return the number model and output it but it showed nothing.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  numbers(){
    return this.get("store").findAll('number')
  }

});
```

I tried it also with the `params.phone_id` as argument but it did not work. (no error was shown also).

the template `phone.hbs` looks like

```
<h5> Device Id: {{model.device_id}}</h5>


{{#each numbers as |number|}}
{{number.digits}}
{{/each}}
```

funny thing is `model.device_id` returns the correct one even though I did not even set it to return that in `phone.js` route. But the each loop for `numbers` which I did implement something for does not return anything.

Is there a workaround to return number model data in `phone.hbs` dynamic segment template ?

**EDIT**:

the way I am reaching my dynamic segment is through a link to:

```
{{#each phones as |phone|}}
    <li>{{#link-to 'phone' phone}} {{phone.id}}{{/link-to}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only object from returned from model hook of route is set as model of controller.

if you want to use numbers as it is in template then write it as a computed property in controller.

```
numbers:Ember.computed(function(){
  return this.store.findAll('number');
});
```

or you can set these properties in model itself

so model hook of your route will look like this

```
model:function(params){
 return Ember.RSVP.hash({
   phone: this.store.findRecord('phone',params.phone_id),
   numbers: this.store.findAll('number')
 });
}
```

after this you will get two properties in your model

Now your template will look like this

```
<h5> Device Id: {{model.phone.device_id}}</h5>


{{#each model.numbers as |number|}}
{{number.digits}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: These does not work in the `phone.hbs` template but works in other templates. seems like model is overwritten because it is a dynamic segment

Comment: tell me one thing are u reachig this dynamic segment route through linkTo? if you are using linkto and passing a phoneModel as param insted of id then model hook is skipped in that case and controller model will be set to the model u passed from linkTo.

Comment: yes I am, please see my edit, and let me know how I can pass id instead of model param as you were mentioning.

Comment: `{{#link-to 'phone' phone.id}}{{phone.id}}{{/link-to}}`

Or using the shorthand/non-block version:

`{{link-to phone.id "phone" phone.id}}`